# Get XML And Entity of REST Request

Tags: javascript, jax-rs

I have a Java REST webservice with a method like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/send")
public Response sendStuff(Stuff stuff) {
    // do magic with stuff
    return Response.ok("OK.").build();
}
```

For debugging purposes I'd like to have the sent XML additionally to `Stuff`.

Now I can marshal the send object manually. Then I would get an entirely different XML which might be missing a few elements or attributes.

Or I can inject the XML and parse it myself, but that's a bit blunt and I might be missing out on webservice functionality like interceptors.

Is there a better way to get both the XML and the Java entity from a JAX-RS webservice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be a right way I decided to go with that:

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/send")
public Response sendStuff(String xml) {
    Stuff stuff;

    try (ByteArrayInputStream inputXml = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()))) {
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Stuff.class);
        request = (Stuff) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(inputXml);
    } catch (final JAXBException | IOException e) {
        return Response.status(400, e.getMessage()).build();
    }

    // do magic with stuff
    return Response.ok("OK.").build();
}
```